# Cursor Alternative to insert rows returned from a function?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am sending a concatenated string consisting of a series `Tax-Value` pair to the database to split and then insert into two columns of a table. I already have a method which uses cursor but i am wondering if there is a *better alternative to cursor* in this case?

My string looks like this: `VAT|10#CST|20#ST|30#VAT|40#WCT|50#OCT|60#FP|70#CD|80#OT|90#`

Tax and value are separated by `|` and Rows are separated by `#`

I use a function to split this string :
Eg:-

```
 select * from isplit('VAT|10#CST|20#ST|30#VAT|40#WCT|50#OCT|60#FP|70#CD|80#OT|90#','#')
```

Which returns 9 rows first cell consisting of `identity srno` and second one consisting of `tax|value`

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ISplit](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))            
RETURNS @Results TABLE (SrNo int identity, Items nvarchar(4000))            
AS            
BEGIN            
    DECLARE @INDEX INT            
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)    
    SELECT @INDEX = 1             
    IF @String IS NULL RETURN            
    WHILE @INDEX !=0            
        BEGIN          
         SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)             
         IF @INDEX !=0            
          SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)            
         ELSE            
          SELECT @SLICE = @STRING            
         INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)            
         SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)    
         IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK            
    END            
    RETURN            
END
```

I am planning on splitting the concatenated string into a #temp table and then using a cursor to split it again and store it in #temp1 table and then using this #temp1 to insert the two column values ie. Tax and Value. `insert into sometable (tax,value) values(@tax,@value)`

```
select * into #temp from split('VAT|10#CST|20#ST|30#VAT|40#WCT|50#OCT|60#FP|70#CD|80#OT|90#','#')
DECLARE @row varchar(20)
DECLARE @Temp CURSOR
SET @Temp = CURSOR FOR
SELECT *
FROM #temp
OPEN @Temp
FETCH NEXT
FROM @Temp INTO @row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @row
select * into #temp1 from iSplit(@row,'|')
declare @tax varchar(10)
declare @value varchar(10)
select @tax= items from #temp1 where srno=1
select @value= items from #temp1 where srno=2
insert into sometable (tax,value) values(@tax,@value)

FETCH NEXT
FROM @Temp INTO @row
END
CLOSE @Temp
DEALLOCATE @Temp
```

is there an alternative to cursor or for statement in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this u needed?

without changing the function:

```
INSERT INTO sometable
            (tax,
             value)
SELECT Substring(items, 0, Charindex('|', items, 0))              AS tax,
       Substring(items, Charindex('|', items, 0) + 1, Len(items)) AS value
FROM   [Isplit]('VAT|10#CST|20#ST|30#VAT|40#WCT|50#OCT|60#FP|70#CD|80#OT|90#', '#')
```

Change the function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ISplit](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))            
RETURNS @Results TABLE (SrNo int identity, tax nvarchar(4000),value numeric(22,6))            
AS            
BEGIN            
    DECLARE @INDEX INT            
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)    
    SELECT @INDEX = 1             
    IF @String IS NULL RETURN            
    WHILE @INDEX !=0            
        BEGIN          
         SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)             
         IF @INDEX !=0            
          SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)            
         ELSE            
          SELECT @SLICE = @STRING            

         INSERT INTO @Results(tax,value) 
         select Substring(@SLICE, 0, Charindex('|', @SLICE, 0)),
         Substring(@SLICE, Charindex('|', @SLICE, 0) + 1, Len(@SLICE)) AS value           

         SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)    

         IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK            
    END            
    RETURN            
END 

 INSERT INTO sometable
                (tax,
                 value)
SELECT tax,value from Isplit('VAT|10#CST|20#ST|30#VAT|40#WCT|50#OCT|60#FP|70#CD|80#OT|90#', '#')
```

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to Cursor and looping. If any.

Comment: My above answer is a straight forward answer if i got your expectation right.Only the function is needed.Nothing else

Comment: Your query is working fine. But I wonder which one is faster? 
Faster or not if there are no better alternatives posted I will mark your answer soon.

Comment: Another thought> you can avoid the function and use the while loop directly.At the end you will need a kind loop somewhere to parse the string operations